# how to refine my Data in the COlumn for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

New to Power BI/DAX so trying to understand how to correctly return what I'm asking for.

**myColumn** contains the following values  (A+,A,A-,B+,B,B-,C+,C,C-,"",*NULL*)

Used the following DAX:  **myCustomColumn** = (Left('myTable'[myColumn],1))

This Returns the Following Values (A,B,C,"",*NULL*)

I apologize for generality of my question but am struggling on how to approach the next piece.

I want to refine the values even further so I remove Nulls and Empty string and only Return (A,B,C)
how would I go about this? Would i filter and if so can someone show me how to do this. I've researched this and not sure I know how to apply the syntactically. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**  Took my original 2 columns and did the following:

```
newTable = 
SUMMARIZE(myTable
,myTable[myColumn]
,"name",SUM(myTable[myColumn2])
)
```

It gives me this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's a calculated column, then it has to have the same number of rows as the rest of the table, so I'm not sure how you expect this to work.

Comment: Table = GROUPBY(myTable,myTable[myColumn],"name",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),myTable[myColumn2]))    seems to yield the same problem  I am getting my desired sum but it's not breaking down by groups

Comment: Please edit the questions to include an example table and your desired result.

Comment: @AlexisOlson updated thanks!

Comment: Still not really clear. What do your original two columns look like?